# Which Live action The Jungle Book adaptation is more faithful to Kipling's novel?

Tags: book-adaptation, the-jungle-book-2016, adaptation, mowgli-legend-of-the-jungle

Which Live action *The Jungle Book* movie adaptation is more faithful to Kipling's novel? I always heard some claims that Disney animated film was not a faithful adaptation and made more into kid friendly movie than novel has ever been.

But what about the live action version, The Jungle Book (2016) and *Mowgli: Legend of the Jungle(2018)*?

Which one is more faithful to the novel?

Comment: King Louie is exclusive to the Disney versions. That alone puts efforts such as *Mowgli* ahead.

Comment: Must the answer choose between the 2016 and 2018 versions, or can the answer be broadened to other, earlier live-action adaptations?

Comment: @vsz that can work as additional value but I don;t want to make it too broad

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [Screenrant](https://screenrant.com/netflix-mowgli-disney-jungle-book-movie-comparison/), it's Andy Serkis' Mowgli: Legend of the Jungle.

> Andy Serkis' Mowgli: Legend of the Jungle is now available on Netflix,
>   and it will undoubtedly be compared to Disney's live-action Jungle
>   Book movie, which was directed by Jon Favreau. Several years ago,
>   Serkis aimed to tell the definitive version of Mowgli's story, a
>   character from Rudyard Kipling's The Jungle Book and The Second Jungle
>   Book novels, which have been comprised into the collection All the
>   Mowgli Stories. It took many years, but it's now out and available to
>   audiences worldwide.
>
> Even though Mowgli: Legend of the Jungle earned some brutal reviews,
>   it's a decent story and an ambitious take on the iconic Jungle Book
>   character. Despite the unevenness in its story, Netflix's Mowgli is a
>   much more accurate adaptation of Kipling's Jungle Book novels than any
>   other mainstream movie adaptation in the past, which primarily means
>   Disney's animated Jungle Book movie from 1967 and Favreau's
>   live-action Jungle Book movie from 2016.